# Unexpected results from MKCoordinateForMapPoint

Tags: swift2

in the code snippet below, I am getting unexpected results from the call to MKCoordinateForMapPoint.

```
let firstPoint = MKPointAnnotation()
let firstPointLocation = MKMapPointMake(41.8735923, -87.6764638) 
print("firstPointLocation: \(firstPointLocation)")
// Prints: firstPointLocation: MKMapPoint(x: 41.8735923, y:-87.6764638)
let firstPointCoordinates = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(firstPointLocation)
print("firstPointCoordinates: \(firstPointCoordinates)") 
// Prints: firstPointCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 85.0511389233241, longitude: -179.999943843137)
firstPoint.coordinate = firstPointCoordinates
print("firstPoint.coordinate: \(firstPoint.coordinate)")
// Prints: firstPoint.coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 85.0511389233241, longitude: -179.999943843137)
firstPoint.title = "Cook County Hospital"
mapView.addAnnotation(firstPoint)
```

As you will see from the output of the second print statement above, the call to MKCoordinateForMapPoint converts the coordinates to something else. Consequently the point does not appear where it is expected. If I replace the MKCoordinateForMapPoint line with the one below, then the point displays correctly.

```
firstPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.8735923, longitude: -87.6764638)
print("firstPoint.coordinate: \(firstPoint.coordinate)") 
// Prints: firstPoint.coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.8735923, longitude: -87.6764638)
```

I checked the reference for MKCoordinateForMapPoint and it is supposed to take in a type MKMapPoint and convert it to a type CLLocationCoordinate2D:

```
func MKCoordinateForMapPoint(_ mapPoint: MKMapPoint) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

Do you have any idea why I am not getting the desired results here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is doing exactly what it is supposed to, however you are misusing `MKMapPointMake`

MKMapPointMake creates a point from a CGPoint (in relation to its frame) not from a lat/lng.

i think the root of the problem is simply confusion, or a Silly Goof. consider renaming your variables so they aren't so similar.

Comment: MKMapPointMake is useful if you want to convert a CGPoint on the screen to a lat/lng.

Comment: Huh? When I look at the reference for this method at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/, there is no reference to CGPoint. According to what they say, it takes in a MKMapPoint type and returns a CLLocationCoordinate2D type. Furthermore, the MKMapPoint is defined as a struct with two Double types. No CGPoints are even mentioned.

Comment: sorry, i used CGPoint to try and convey that the X and Y values are in relation to the bounds of the MKMapView. 

say you wanted the lat/lng of the origin of your map, you'd do ```MKMapPointMake(0,0)``` and then convert it using ```MKCoordinateForMapPoint```

Comment: Casey, I do appreciate your help to understand this! :)